# i0S11 WKWebView or UIWebView not scrolling on Anchor click

Tags: scroll, uiwebview, anchor, wkwebview, ios11

Since iOS 11 the "anchor" present in my webview are not working anymore.
I first thought it was time to migrate from UIWebView to WKWebview so I proceed, but this is still not working.

I can't find any response over the web.

Can any one help me please ?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE :

```
//anchor ?
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"11.0"))
{
    NSArray * spliting = [stringUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
    if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated && [spliting count] == 2)
    {
        NSString * anchor = spliting.lastObject;
        //[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.location.hash = '#%@';",anchor]]; // not working in iOS11
        NSString* code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"el = document.getElementsByName(\"%@\")[0]; if (el) el.scrollIntoView();", anchor];
        (void) [webView evaluateJavaScript:code completionHandler:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554163/wkwebview-anchor-tags-within-same-page-not-woking - I would suggest, as I say there, that this is just a straightforward old-fashioned bug and you should file it with Apple.